# Confused about the relation between BRST invariant states and 'group averaging'

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, constrained-dynamics, brst

https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0111270 by O.Y. Shvedov tries to relate the '*group averaging procedure*' (see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group+averaging and references therein) to the BRST formalism so that group averaging can be made sense of for **open** Lie algebras.

I have a question about the technicalities of the paper. According to (3.6) a Dirac state $\Psi(q)$ is related to a BRST invariant state $\Upsilon$ by
$$
\Psi(q)=\int d\mu ~d\Pi~ d\bar\Pi~\Upsilon(q,-i\mu,\Pi,\bar\Pi).\tag{3.6}
$$
(This relation is clear to me — if $\Upsilon$ is a BRST invariant state, then $\Psi(q)$ is annihilated by the constraints (proved on page 10), making it a Dirac state.)

According to the 2nd formula in section C of page 10, a Dirac state $\Psi(q)$ is related to an 'auxiliary state' $\Phi$ by
$$
\Psi(q)=\int d\mu ~d\Pi~ d\bar\Pi~e^{[\Omega,\rho]_{+}}\Phi(q,-i\mu,\Pi,\bar\Pi), \tag{p.10}
$$
where $\Omega$ is the BRST generator and $\rho$ is the 'gauge fixing fermion'.

Comparing these expressions, it seems to me that he's setting
$$\Upsilon =e^{[\Omega,\rho]_{+}}\Phi.\tag{*}$$ But how does it follow that $\Upsilon$ is actually BRST invariant?

Answer (score 1):

That eq. ($*$) is BRST-closed follows by Taylor expanding the exponential function:

- The leading term $\Phi$ is BRST-closed $\Omega\Phi=0$ by assumption.
- All the subleading terms are BRST-exact (and hence BRST-closed as well). To prove the latter we used the fact that we can replace the anti-commutator $[\Omega,\rho]_{+} \to \Omega\rho$ in eq. ($*$) because $\Phi$ is BRST-closed and $\Omega^2=0$ nilpotent.