# Does the following limit exist in the BRST formalism?

Tags: operators, hilbert-space, gauge-theory, constrained-dynamics, brst

Consider the BRST operator $\Omega$ (which has ghost number $+1$) and the gauge fermion operator $\rho$ which has ghost number $-1$. Given an exact state $|\Phi\rangle$ (i.e. $|\Phi\rangle=\Omega|\Psi\rangle$) is it reasonable to suppose that
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-t[\Omega,\rho]_+}|\Phi\rangle=0\tag{1}
$$
I feel this should be true since

1. $e^{-t[\Omega,\rho]_+}$ is damping for large $t$.
2. $|\Phi\rangle$ is in the universality class of $0$. (two states are *equivalent* if related by an exact state.)
3. $e^{-t[\Omega,\rho]_+}|\Phi\rangle=|\Phi\rangle+\text{an exact state}$ (this follows from expanding the exponential and using $\Omega^2=0$ and $\Omega|\Phi\rangle=0$), which means $e^{-t[\Omega,\rho]_+}$ moves $|\Phi\rangle$ around within its universality class, cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/756445/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: Is this from a reference?

Comment: @Qmechanic Not exactly. The reason I'm asking is because if this was true then it's also true that $\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-t[\Omega,\rho]}|\Psi\rangle$ is BRST invariant for arbitrary $|\Psi\rangle$, which gives us a way of (formally) constructing BRST invariant states.

Comment: Just want to clarify that the previous statement follows from the fact that $\Omega$ commutes with $e^{-t[\Omega,\rho]}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we choose $\rho = {}^*\Omega$ (the co-BRST operator), then the answer is yes! This is because $[\Omega,{}^*\Omega]_+$ is the BRST Laplacian which is a semi-positive definite (self-adjoint) operator.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, note that $H:=[\Omega,\rho]_{+}=H^{\dagger}$ is self-adjoint, because $\Omega=\Omega^{\dagger}$ and $\rho=\rho^{\dagger}$ are.
2. For $e^{-tH}\to 0$ for $t\to\infty$ to hold we need furthermore that $H$ is a [semi-positive definite operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_operator_(Hilbert_space)). It is not clear that that is true in general. It would imply
   $$\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-tH}|\Psi\rangle=|\Psi\rangle.$$
3. It is not clear why OP's eq. (1) should hold in general for BRST-exact states.